# Atomic Concepts

Tags: visualization, linguistics, word-cloud

```
WordCloud[WikipediaData["model theory"]]
```

[image]

That is where it starts.  I want to now find a new WordCloud with the center inset from the prevous Wordcloud. TIA

Comment: Best if you clarify the output you want.  A mock up or a drawing would help.

Answer (score 5):

Still guessing at what you want, but the following came to mind...

```
wcMedium = 
 WordCloud[WikipediaData["model theory"], ImageSize -> Medium];
wcLarge = 
 WordCloud[WikipediaData["model theory"], ImageSize -> Large, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["GrayTones"], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];

ImageCompose[wcLarge, Medium]
```

[image]

---

In response to the OP's comment,

> I just want to take the central word in a word cloud like
> WordCloud[WikipediaData[RandomWord[]]] and turn the center word into a
> useable string. For example, "Model Theory" might be the center of a
> word cloud in which case, "Model Theory" is the result.

it doesn't seem he needs to use `WordCloud` at all.
Rather:

```
First[
Keys[
  WordCounts[
   DeleteStopwords[WikipediaData["model theory"]]
   ]
  ]
]
```

Which returns:

> theory

The code:

- gets rid of stopwords,
- `WordCounts` the remaining words outputting
  an `Association` of ranked occurrences.
- `Keys` extracts a list of words themselves from the `Association`.
- `First` extracts the most used word from the list.

Comment: Thanks.  Nice image.  I just want to take the central word in a word cloud like $ $WordCloud[WikipediaData[RandomWord[]]] and turn the center word into a useable string.  For example, "Model Theory" might be the center of a word cloud in which case, "Model Theory" is the result.